# Alpha fade not working in Imageview animation

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I'm trying to swap two images in separate Imageviews with a fade-out/fade-in.  The first image fades out, then the other image fades out, then the second image fades in while replaced with the first image, then the first image fades back in while being replaced with the second image (swap images with fade out/in). The code is below.  The swap is occurring okay but there is no fade out or in. What am I missing to get the alpha fade to occur? Also, if I use an integer (such as 1500) instead of mShortAnimationDuration, the animationlistener does not get triggered.  setDuration argument is type long. I based my code on the example from here: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

```
    Drawable target_draw = target.getDrawable();
    Drawable dragged_draw = dragged.getDrawable();
    final Bitmap targetBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)target_draw).getBitmap();
    final Bitmap draggedBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)dragged_draw).getBitmap();

    //SWAP and CROSSFADE ANIMATION
    dragged.setAlpha(1f);
    target.setAlpha(1f);

    int mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

     dragged.animate()
         .alpha(0f)
         .setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration)
         .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {            
               @Override
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                   dragged.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
                   dragged.invalidate();
                }
           });


     target.animate()
         .alpha(0f)
         .setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration)
         .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
             @Override
             public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                 target.setImageBitmap(draggedBitmap);
                 target.invalidate();
             }
         });

     //fade in with new images
     target.animate()
         .alpha(1f)
         .setDuration(1500);


     dragged.animate()
         .alpha(1f)
         .setDuration(1500);
```

UPDATE:
I finally came up with the following code which basically works, but due to the fact that Android is not a real-time OS, and that fact that I am swapping images and calling invalidate() during the fade transitions, makes the timing of the fades somewhat unpredictable.

```
dragged.animate()
    .alpha(0f)
    .setDuration(1000)
    //.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()) //optional
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            dragged.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
            dragged.invalidate();
            dragged.animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                //.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                .setDuration(1000);
                //.setStartDelay(500); //also optional for timing
                }
         });


 target.animate()
     .alpha(0f)
     .setDuration(1000)
     .setStartDelay(500)
     //.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
     .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
         target.setImageBitmap(draggedBitmap);
         target.invalidate();
         target.animate()
         .alpha(1f)
         //.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
         //.setStartDelay(500)
         .setDuration(1000);
      }
  });
```

...update continued:
Since the timing of the fades were inconsistent due to image swapping during them, I simplified and eliminated the fade-out, and just kept the image swap and fade-in. This is the code I ended up with.  I am looking for more interesting ways to animate Imageview swapping if anyone has any ideas on that.

```
// swap
            dragged.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
            dragged.invalidate();
            target.setImageBitmap(draggedBitmap);
            target.invalidate();

            // then fade-in with delay
            Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            Animation fadeIn2 = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeIn2.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            fadeIn2.setStartOffset(300);
            fadeIn.setDuration(2000);
            fadeIn2.setDuration(2000);
            target.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            dragged.startAnimation(fadeIn2);
```